# convert json string to multi dimension array

Tags: javascript, json

I have data like this

```
 [[[[2,5],[1,2],[null,null],[1,null],[1,2],[null,null],[2,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[3,2],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],[[2,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[1,2],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null]]]]
```

I wanna convert that data to multidimension array ,(exactly is 4 dimension).
Any suggest what should i do?

Comment: please add the wanted result and what you have tried.

Comment: Have you tried [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: `var array = JSON.parse(yourstring);`

Comment: It basically already is a multi-dimensional array. It's arrays in an array (that's what the [] symbols mean). It depends on how you want to consume that data. For instance making it associative (give every level a string key). You can make a loop in a loop to do this. Or better, write a recursive function.

Comment: This JSON already contains a multidimensional Array *(even looks like 4 dimensions, at a first glance)*. So what's the problem/question?

Comment: nah JSON.parse is worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prse the json string using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.

```js
var str = '[[[[2,5],[1,2],[null,null],[1,null],[1,2],[null,null],[2,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[3,2],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],[[2,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[1,2],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null],[null,null],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null]],[[null,null],[null,null]]]]';

console.log(JSON.parse(str));
```